# When Passing Data Via Props From Laravel, Vue Component Not Rendering, Dumping Data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting odd unexpected behavior that I can't seem to find a solution for, and this is the second time it has happened.

Whenever I try to pass Laravel data to a Vue component via props, instead of assigning the value to the prop, it seems to dump the data out to the DOM, and then the component never renders.

In a .vue single file component, I define my props like so:

```
props: {
    businesses: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
},
```

In my Laravel Controller, I have the data like so

```
$a = new \stdClass();
$a->name = 'tester';
$a->id = 5;
$a->desc = "This is getting a bit ridiculous now";

$b = new \stdClass();
$b->name = 'Boo ya';
$b->id = 2;
$b->desc = "Certainly really annoying to me";
$testStuff = [$a, $b];

return view(
    "businessListing",
    compact('testStuff')
);
```

In my Laravel Blade template, I have my component setup like this:

```
<business-listing :businesses="@json($testStuff)"></business-listing>
```

Also tried this, even though should be the same, and it provided same result.

```
<business-listing :businesses="{!! json_encode($testStuff) !!}"></business-listing>
```

Then instead of the component being rendered, I see a mashed up version of the json string, the mounted() function never fires, but also no errors in console.

":"tester","id":5,"desc":"this="" is="" getting="" a="" bit="" ridiculous="" now"},{"name":"boo="" ya","id":2,"desc":"certainly="" really="" annoying="" to="" me"}]"="">

[image: Component Error]

If I pass in an empty array, the component renders, mounted() fires as expected, and dumps the empty array to console.

[image: Component Success]

Has anybody else run into this? I cannot figure out what is wrong for the life of me. I should mention - Laravel 5.7/PHP 7.1, Vue 2.5.17.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the single quotes around `'{ ... }'`:

```
<business-listing :businesses="'{!! json_encode($testStuff) !!}'"></business-listing>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I gave it a shot. But unfortunately that does not seem to be the problem, still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

@DigitalDrifter's answer inspired me to mess with the quotes.

It seems that having the first set of double quotes "" was the problem?

If I just use the single quotes, that seems to work. I am not sure why that is the case, any other examples I have looked at, seem to have both, as DigitalDrifter's shows.  Working example below.

```
<business-listing :businesses='{!! json_encode($testStuff) !!}'></business-listing>
```

Comment: The array does not need an extra encoding.. {!! $testStuff !!}